# chicken schemeにおけるimport と useの違い。

Tags: lisp, scheme

最近、scheme処理系の一つであるchicken schemeで遊んでいるのですが、
chickenではモジュールのロードの方法に大きく use と、importの二種類があるようです。
そこでお尋ねしたいのですが、use とimport の違いは何でしょうか。
また、どのように使い分けたらいいのでしょうか。
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

importはモジュールのロードは行いません。既にロードもしくはリンクされているモジュールを、現在の名前空間から見えるようにするだけです。

http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Modules#import

useはモジュールを（必要なら）ロードした上でimportを行います。

http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Non-standard%20macros%20and%20special%20forms#making-extra-libraries-and-extensions-available

Comment: shirokさん、ご解答ありがとうございます。
なるほど、そのような違いがあったのですか……。
どうもchickenの名前空間・library・moduleの関係について、判っていなかったようです。
もう少し勉強してみます。

Comment: @Rio: 解決したら解決済みのマークを付けてもらえますか？　回答の左側に「✓」みたいなボタンがあると思いますので、それをクリックすると解決済みとなります。